# Checkbox not rendering properly

Tags: android, checkbox

I am having two checkboxes in my layout as follows

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_mysources_photogallery"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:button="@drawable/toggle_button"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_mysources_picasa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:button="@drawable/toggle_button"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

All devices render this properly:

[image]

But in Samsung S2 with android 2.3 is displaying it like:

[image]

Any ideas why can this be happening? The checkbox is supported by all android versions.

**EDIT:** 
[Here](http://pastie.org/9975200) is the toggle_button.xml

Here are the images inside button:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to put into the root layout this: android:weightSum="2"

Comment: @programmer23 it's generally better to let the system calculate the `weightSum` which is what will happen if that property is left out.

Comment: provide please "@drawable/toggle_button"

Comment: I think you want to a [SwitchCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html) widget instead of checkbox